# Create new sheet and organize result

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a report from Cognos which is generating the result below in Excel format:

The problem with the code is everything I have hardcoded the values based on line numbers and which I want to make dynamic, so that if I have to generate a report for the previous 2 weeks, then I won't have to change my macro code every time.

Currently I am showing the value for `name` = "PO" and `id` = 28. But there will be other `name` and `id` also. For every `name` and `id` there will be 4 column values as for `RR`, `DD`, `EE` and `FF`. I have to group them based on `name` and `id` and create new sheet which will have results like below:

Comment: You need to seach for each entity and establish it's row, column etc. 
It's possible, I've done it. You need to define your own structure to search though.

Comment: Also, it's best to [avoid using `.Select`/`.Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/), which also will help cut down the code length.  Also, it looks like mainly you just need to get your headers set up, and you could use `Index/Match()`, no? (Perhaps with multiple criteria)

Comment: yes but i am quiet new to vba coding ang getting idea about the same

Comment: You can do all this without VBA. Have a look at Get & Transform on the Data tab

Comment: ... with all respect Andrew!

Comment: @Sam without VBA how can we dont ?thanks.

Comment: I repeat: You cannot do this unless you are fluent in VBA. Now you are way out your league. Sorry

Comment: @peakpeak if you can do this please help me

Comment: When I started programming in 1980 there was noone to ask. Today we have Google. Learn from it!

Answer (score 1):

Andrew: What version of Excel do you have? If you have Excel 2013 or later, you can use the new functionality under the 'Get and Transform' tab to do this really easily. It was previously a separate add-in called PowerQuery, and is now bulk standard in Excel.

There's many excellent walkthroughs on the internet showing this exact type of activity. Google "PowerQuery"  and put a date filter on your results to show just the last year, as the functionality is constantly being updated. Add "Ken Puls" to your search term, and see what bubbles to the top. Then replace Ken "Mike Girvin" or "ExcelIsFun" and you should see like a zillion excellent tutorials on PowerQuery. Try "ExcelCampus" too, as Jon has great tutorials, as does "Chandoo". Also replace PowerQuery with "Get and Transform" and repeat those same searches.

PowerQuery is simple to learn, and lets you do stuff just by "muddling through" that would otherwise take a year or more to learn if you wanted to pick up VBA.

It acts like a user-friendly macro recorder, only unlike the macro recorder it spits out reusable code that doesn't have hard coded references in it.

Comment: thanks for your information i am just going through get and transform functionality. Just wanted to know for my example do you suggest any specific tutorial which i look into. Otherwiese i have to spend lot of time by learning through all the functionality of get and transform ?

Comment: It won't take you too long to find something similar, using those names I gave you as google filters. And then you'll quickly see just how easy it is to muddle through using this tool. I use it all the time to do stuff that I have no idea how to do, and I've found time and time again that the tool is very forgiving to lack of knowledge.